# Azure DevOps Server - enter proper license on brand new DevOps Server RC2?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server, azure-devops-server-2019

I recently installed the new DevOps Server RC2 on my Windows Server. I decided to end the trial evaluation mode. However i find nowhere i can enter a proper license for DevOps Server or configure paid users.

[image]

Comment: I haven't installed VSTS/Azure DevOps on a server in years. Can you indicate if it still is in the same place as in TFS? See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/upgrade/change-product-key

Comment: @RobBos Yes i've followed instructions, specially these ones : 

Open the administration console of Team Foundation Server. Expand the name of the server, and review the information in Product ID, License Type, and License Expires. 

However, i have no information displayed about any installed license.

Comment: Now I am curious to see if anything was there ;-). Maybe a screenshot would help.

Comment: Try re-installing RTW now that it has been released.